# xampp - connecting to a local database from another local machine inside a LAN

Tags: mysql, xampp, remote-access

I am using XAMPP to create php projects.
My system is: name=con7 and local ip=192.168.1.20
Another system is: name=con12 and local ip=19.168.1.10

I want to connect to a database in con12 from con7.

I read that we need to provide access permission for the host(ip) which is trying to connect from a different machine like the Access Host in cPanel->databases (the control panel for linux hostings).

I have access to that system as that person(con7) does the data entry and me the manipulation.
some thing like that.

So how to do this?

Comment: Which system out of the two is the database hosted on?

Comment: con12 is the system which is having the database and i want to access that from con7... me too having xampp installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect to a remote database you have to make sure:

- The mysql-server has to listen on a public interface (e.g. eth0) in order to be accessable via lan. This can be checked via telnet on port 3306 (default mysql port)
- The mysql-user must be allowed to connect at least from 192.168.1.20 or % (i.e. all hosts)
- The mysql-user must have read (+write) permissions for the database

Do you want to run an PHP-script adding the correct credentials in mysql_connect() should suffice. If you want to use your local phpmyadmin to work with the database you have to add the database in the phpmyadmin-config.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where do we grant the permission.
In which file?
or... from the command line?

when i tried telnet con12 3306 i got the following reply
[[con7 is not allowed to connect to this MYSQL server]]

So it is clear that any other ip is denied.

Is there any interface to grant permission?